# JTextField Outputting

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

How do you output a number in the JTextField? I need to add age when inputs and display it back to him.

```
    age = new JTextField();
    age.setBounds(10, 133, 108, 20);
    contentPane.add(age);
    age.setColumns(10);

    textArea = new JTextField();
    textArea.setBounds(10, 198, 298, 20);
    contentPane.add(textArea);

    JButton btnDisplayWelcome = new JButton("Submit");
    btnDisplayWelcome.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            String first = firstname.getText();
            String last = lastname.getText();

            textArea.setText("Welcome " + first + ", " + last + " of ");
        }
    });
```

Comment: You don't use `null` layouts. You could use `Inetger.toString` (or other `Number` equivalent) or `String.valueOf` or a `JSpinner` or `JFormattedTextField`

Comment: `textArea = new JTextField();`  That's a good (OK reasonable) name for a `JTextArea` but a bad name for a `JTextField`!

Comment: @MadProgrammer  *"You don't use `null` layouts."* Excellent point.  In this case, the OP might start by defining the number of columns (characters) for the text field to display.  I typically do it in the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do you output a number in the JTextField?

There is a `setText` method which allow you to modify it contents.

```
age.setText(String.valueOf(950));
```

See [`JTextComponent.setText(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText-java.lang.String-) for details.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Once again, thanks for noticing one of my typo :)

Comment: I'm great at recognizing typos.  Now if there were only bucket loads of cash to be found in that ability.. ;)